# Unable to received FCM web push notifications, and not getting any error either

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send FCM push notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) in laravel, It was working fine till last night and I was receiving notifications, but now it is not sending notifications and also not returning any error instead giving me success status.

I have verified device tokens are valid, permissions are enabled.

I am using https://github.com/agence-appy/fcmhttpv1 this package.

Here is my code of service worker:

```
/* Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging. Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries are not available in the service worker. */ importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts( "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-messaging.js" );

/* Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the messagingSenderId.
New configuration for app@pulseservice.com */
firebase.initializeApp({ apiKey: "", authDomain: "", projectId: "", storageBucket: "", messagingSenderId: "", appId: "*", });

self.addEventListener("push", function (event) { var data = event.data.json().data;

const title = data.title;
//data.Data.actions = data.Actions;
const options = {
    body: data.body,
    icon: data.icon,
    image: data.image,
    data: data.action,
};
event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));

});

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) { console.log(event.notification); //var data = event.data.json().data; event.notification.close(); event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data)); });

self.addEventListener("notificationclose", function (event) {});
```

And code for sending notification:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications\Store;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable; use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue; use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage; use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification; use App\Notifications\Channels\FirebaseChannel; use Exception; use GuzzleHttp\Client; use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log; use Appy\FcmHttpV1\FcmGoogleHelper; use Appy\FcmHttpV1\FcmNotification;

class NewOrder extends Notification { 
use Queueable;
/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return FirebaseChannel::class;
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toFirebase($notifiable)
{
    $notif = new FcmNotification();
    $notif->setTitle("New Order Recived")->setBody("New Order Recieved")
        ->setToken($notifiable->devicetokens->first()->token)->setClickAction(route('order.new'))->send();
}
/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{

    return [
        //
    ];
}
}
```

I have tried with multiple tokens and devices, but not getting any luck.

**SOLVED**
There was an error in the service worker file.
The new file code is

```
/*
Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries are not available in the service worker.
*/
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts(
    "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-messaging.js"
);

/*
Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the messagingSenderId.
* New configuration for app@pulseservice.com
*/
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
});

/*
Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background messages.
*/
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log(
        "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
        payload
    );
    /* Customize notification here */
    const notificationTitle = "Background Message Title";
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: "Background Message body.",
        icon: "/itwonders-web-logo.png",
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(
        notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions
    );
});

self.addEventListener("push", function (event) {
    var data = event.data.json().data;

    const title = data.title;
    //data.Data.actions = data.Actions;
    const options = {
        body: data.body,
        icon: data.icon,
        image: data.image,
        data: data.action,
    };
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
    console.log(event.notification);
    //var data = event.data.json().data;
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data));
});

self.addEventListener("notificationclose", function (event) {});
```

Comment: Were there any changes before you noticed messages stoped working?

Comment: Yes, the problem was BackgroundMessageHandler was missing in the service worker file.